# How to support OpenID Connect standard address (JSON) claim with Azure B2C custom policy?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

How does one map built-in B2C attributes like 'city' to a standard OpenID Connect  claim which uses JSON like 'address.locality' in a custom policy.

There is documentation on JSON claims transformation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations) but I don't see any examples of transforming a set of input claims to a JSON output.

Comment: Please clarify - give an example of what you would like to see in the JWT token. What do you mean by 'standard OpenID Connect claim'? (Your reference is to transforming claim values, not names, which you seem to be asking about)

Comment: Im looking to support the OpenId Connect address claim as documented (here)[https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think AAD supports [JSON object data type for attributes and hence claims of that type:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionschemaproperty?view=graph-rest-beta)